# TFS 2013 imported namespace not resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Using TFS 2013 I have several references that don't resolve.  However, I can't see where you specify where these exist.  Can someone tell me how I can get these to be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my xaml in a project.  I didn't realize the references would be picked up from there, but evidently they are.  I was able to get around my issue by adding a reference to the correct assembly in the project references area.

[image]